# pros and cons of TryCatch versus TryParse

Tags: c#, .net, tryparse, try-catch

What are the pros and cons of using either of the following approaches to pulling out a double from an object? Beyond just personal preferences, issues I'm looking for feedback on include ease of debugging, performance, maintainability etc.

```
public static double GetDouble(object input, double defaultVal)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(input);
     }
     catch
     {
        return defaultVal;
     }
}

public static double GetDouble(object input, double defaultVal)
{
    double returnVal;
    if (double.TryParse(input.ToString(), out returnVal))
    {
        return returnVal;
    }
else
    {
        return defaultVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `TryParse` will be faster than catching an exception
- `TryParse` indicates something *expected* - nothing exceptional is happening here, it's just that you suspect your data may not be valid.
- `TryParse` isn't using exception handling for normal control flow

Basically, go with `TryParse` :)

By the way, your code can be rewritten as:

```
public static double GetDouble(object input, double defaultVal)
{
    double parsed;
    return double.TryParse(input.ToString(), out parsed)) ? parsed : defaultVal;
}
```

Comment: GM Jon,
What is the internal implementation of tryparse() ? 
Is it like this:

try
{
Parse();
return true;
}
catch(Exception)
{
return false;
}

Comment: TryParse casts to String (actually a char*), tries to parse that string to a Number (via character comparisons), then does various other checks (range etc.) to ensure the Number is the correct type. There's not a try catch block around it :)

Answer (score 4):

TryParse is more efficient than TryCatch performance wise.

Answer (score 3):

Having the Parse methods throw exceptions on bad input was a design flaw.  Bad input is *expected* behavior when you take in data from a user.  Exception throwing is expensive, it's not something you want happening routinely in your code.

Thankfully, Microsoft realized their mistake and added the TryParse methods.  TryParse does *not* incur the overhead of exception throwing on bad input, but the downside is it has to return two pieces of data, so it feels a bit awkward to use.

Now if they hadn't created the broken Parse implemetation in the first place, TryParse would just be called Parse.

Answer (score 2):

TryParse is faster and usually better but I would suggest the TryCatch approach in framework and back-end programming because you can give more information to the client about the error:

```
public double GetAge()
{
   try
   {
      var input = _dataProvider.GetInput();
      return Convert.ToDouble(input);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      throw new MyBackendException(ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: You could still use TryParse and raise your own exception on bad data. In fact, you should do it that way, for tracing purposes if nothing else.

Comment: Ok, but you would have only a generic message about "bad data" and you will loose the information about why data is bad. Information that is in an InvalidCastException or a FormatException or . Programming on a given framework I would like as much as possible info about an error.

Anyway, when bad data could come from a web service or from storage it's not a "expected behavior" and IMO exception must be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is better to proactively look or check for the input against using `try catch` block.
Example if we have a dictionary with lookup table for ineteger to string conversion it is good performance wise if we just use `ContainsKey` instead of using `try catch` for checking the key