# How to parse a string to integer?

Tags: c#, tryparse

I want to use the `CalcEngine` library for doing mathematic calculations in textboxes. The following codes are a part of the whole project. Why is it giving an error? The error is in `CE.Evaluate(textBoxTLA.Text).ToString()`. The error says:

> Argument 2 should be passed by out keyword.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalcEngine.CalcEngine CE = new CalcEngine.CalcEngine();
        int.TryParse(textBoxTLA.Text, CE.Evaluate(textBoxTLA.Text).ToString());

    }
```

Comment: What error is it giving you? We can't help much without knowing that.

Comment: The error is in "CE.Evaluate(textBoxTLA.Text).ToString()" part. The IDE underlines this section of the code

Comment: The second argument should be the destination variable (`int`). You're passing `CE.Evaluate(textBoxTLA.Text).ToString()`

Comment: @Fardin when you hover over it, or look into the message, it should show a description of the error.

Comment: It says, "Argument 2 should be passed by out keyword"

Comment: What are you trying to do... This code doesn't make any sense at all. I am guessing Evaluate would return a double. why are you wanting to parse it again? are you trying to put the results in another textbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) takes an integer as a second parameter, and you are supplying a `String`.

It works like this (I don't know which string you want parsed, I assumed the evaluated one):

```
int target;
CalcEngine.CalcEngine CE = new CalcEngine.CalcEngine();
int.TryParse(CE.Evaluate(textBoxTLA.Text).ToString(), out target);
```

It is better to use `Parse` though, so you can do correct error handling (plus the code will be more readable).

Also, you are doing a lot in one line, which makes it harder to debug, and to give clear messages to your user. For example, what if `CE.Evaluate` fails?

Comment: Why would one want to evaluate an expression which would result in a numeric type, then project it to a string, the parse it as an int again

Comment: I don't agree, TryParse was made specifically to make error handling easier and make code more readable.. and it does it with less complexity

Comment: Take a look at this: https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/c-tryparse-vs-try-catch

Comment: @audzzy thanks for that, but that talks mainly about performance. OP is clearly a beginning programmer, so I'd advise on writing readable code.

Comment: TryParse also makes it more readable.. it returns if it was successful, like adding a try catch around the parse.. but without having to write it.. all in all cleaner more readable code that runs faster and better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431836/pros-and-cons-of-trycatch-versus-tryparse#:~:text=TryParse%20is%20more%20efficient%20than%20TryCatch%20performance%20wise.&text=Having%20the%20Parse%20methods%20throw,input%20was%20a%20design%20flaw.&text=TryParse%20does%20not%20incur%20the,a%20bit%20awkward%20to%20use.

Comment: There really is no reason to use parse unless you expect invalid number string and want it to raise an exception, and even then it's better to use TryParse and raise the exception you want in a more managed way.. parse was a design flaw that microsoft fixed by adding TryParse

Answer (score 2):

TryParse recieves two parameters, the string you want to parse, and an out parameter that receives the output..

So say my string is `textBoxTLA.Text`, I would parse it to int like this:

```
int myInt;
if(int.TryParse(textBoxTLA.Text, out myInt))
{
//Do whatever you need with calcEngine
}
```

It does this so it can return a bool value of whether or not it succeeded, so if you don't enter the if cause it was not able to parse the int. Make sure to use this and avoid errors and exceptions.